# java.lang.NullPointerException when run on Tomcat 8, iterating files

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception, tomcat8

I am building a project using Tomcat 8. I want to count the words number in all of files in a directory. I write a function and want to make a Rest Api GET request to run the function and return the count. But I encounter a NullPointerException when I test the API call using PostMan. When I run the function at local, it's work good. But the same function cannot work on the Tomcat 8 server.

The following tis the error reported-

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [api.wordNum] in context with path [/Test] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at api.WordCountHandler.countWords(WordCountHandler.java:78)
    at api.wordNum.doGet(wordNum.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The following is my code -

```
public static int countWords() {
    File dir = new File("src/testfiles/");
    int count = 0;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        try {
            Scanner s;
            s = new Scanner(file);
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                count++;
            }
            s.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    return count;
}
```

The Api Call -

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int result = WordCountHandler.countWords();
    response.getWriter().append(Integer.toString(result));
}
```

The NullPointerException is happen at this line-

```
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `listFiles` returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory.  Does `src/testfiles/` exist?   Maybe you should include the full path from the root of the file system.  If you don't, this relative path is under the directory that the code is in.

You should include a line testing `dir.exists()` before the loop, and throw an appropriate error if it does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, the problem fixed after I change the pathname to the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a matter  of relative path. Try with an absolute  file path first.